# Material UI customize property behind classes

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, map-function, prismic.io

I am trying to make an application. And I want to customize the value that comes after `classes.`**something**. The something I want to be a value that comes out of my API.

I made 2 custom CSS classes:

```
new: {
    color: '#0099FF',
  },
improvement: {
    color: '#01C86B',
  },
```

And I get the words **new, improvement** out of my API. I want to add them in the first  Is this even possible? something like `classes.entry.entry_tag`

Because all the tags that are available are in the value entry.entry_tag

```
  const showContent = whatsNewDoc.entries.map(entry => {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.tagTitle}>
          <span className={classes.tagBackground}>{entry.entry_tag}</span>
        </Typography>
        <PrismicContents>{entry.entry_title}</PrismicContents>

        <PrismicContents>{entry.entry_body}</PrismicContents>
        <Divider className={classes.dividerSpace} />
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want.

variable_name = getResponseFromApi()

You can just write `classes[variable_name]` since classes is just an object